# Cannot open output file: bin\Debug\PrimeChecker.exe Permission denied

Tags: c++

so I get this error when I run my program:

```
cannot open output file bin\Debug\PrimeChecker.exe Permission denied
```

I've already searched this and have found that none of the solutions other people had, applied to me.
Things I have already done:

1. Changed the directory
2. Reinstall CodeBlocks
3. Checked task-manager with anything starting with CodeBlocks (is it maybe listed as something else)

I had no problem running CodeBlocks before this happened and then it just started happening out of the blue.

I'm running on windows 7, if that helps...

Comment: Check your anti-virus.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure PrimeChecker.exe is not running (for example, in the debugger) when you build. Chances are - this is your problem.

You can go to bin\Debug\PrimeChecker.exe , and try to delete it. you'll probably will not be able to. so find out who is holding a handle for it. I like to use peocessExplorer for this (download free from MS)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the file you are trying to open in your program hasn't read permission. you should change your file permission to be able to write or read to them. this links should be helpful to change your system file permission or attributes.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7